# Unhide 4 columns with each button press

Tags: excel, vba

I have more than 20 hidden columns with data. I want 4 columns to appear and then the next 4 columns on each click of a button.

I tried the below code. Instead of 4 columns at a time, it shows all 20 columns in a click.

```
Sub compare() ' 
'compare macro 
'selects the button1 rows for the output tab 
application.screenupdating=true  
range("I10:AR62").entirecolumn/hidden=false
range("B1").select  
application.screenupdating=false  
End
```

Comment: entirecolumn/hidden ==>  entirecolumn.hidden

Comment: You need to set-up your groups to account for sets of 4.  You also need to determine how that will work.  Do you want 1 button to cycle through and expand groupings from group 1 (col 1:4), then press again for group 2 (col 5:8), etc.?

Comment: Hi Cyril. Thank you for reply. Yes I want 1 button to cycle through and expand groupings from group 1 (col I:N), then press again for group 2 (Column O:T) and so on. Column A:H is fixed.

Comment: Anyone, please reply. I can't make it

Answer (score 0):

you want something like:

```
range(columns(j),columns(j+k)).entirecolumn.hidden=true
range(columns(y),columns(y+z)).entirecolumn.hidden=false
```

but you need logic to determine what j is... first scenario is where nothing is hidden:

```
if not columns(9).entirecolumn.hidden and not columns(13).entirecolumn.hidden and not columns(17).entirecolumn.hidden and not columns(21).entirecolumn.hidden then
```

Then you will want to hide such that:

```
j = 13
k = 15
```

Where that scenario is not true (ELSE), you should have some logic embedded to determine what is hidden and unhide other sections:

```
if not columns(9).entirecolumn.hidden then 
    j = 9
    k = 3
    y = 13
    z = 3
```

You would need the above for each of your column groupings to tell what isn't hidden, so you know what grouping is next.

You would have listed what sections will be visible and which sections would be hidden based on the column numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a few days since anyone has posted on this, but I figured I would post this part of a macro that I have built for another project. This should work as intended, and the variables are already setup according to the OP's question.

```
Sub DynHideColumns()

FirstColumn = 9 ' First Column that could be hidden
LastColumn = 200 ' Last Column that could be hidden
ColumnSteps = 4 ' Number of columns to hide per start
x = FirstColumn
Z = 1
ReDim y(1 To ColumnSteps)

Do Until x > LastColumn
    If ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(x), Columns(x)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False Then
        If Z <= ColumnSteps Then
            y(Z) = x
            Z = Z + 1
        Else
            y(1) = ""
        End If
    End If
x = x + 1
Loop

ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(FirstColumn), Columns(LastColumn)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True

If y(1) = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(FirstColumn), Columns(FirstColumn + ColumnSteps - 1)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
Else
    If y(ColumnSteps) = LastColumn Then
        ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(FirstColumn), Columns(FirstColumn + ColumnSteps)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    Else
        ActiveSheet.Range(Columns(y(1) + ColumnSteps), Columns(y(ColumnSteps) + ColumnSteps)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Cyril and IrwinAllen 13 for a reply. I have used the below and it is working so well.
Sub UnhideColmns()
Dim c As Range
Dim i, v As Integer
Set c = Range("A1")
For i = 1 To 200
If c.EntireColumn.Hidden = True Then
c.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
v = v + 1
If v = 4 Then Exit For
End If
Set c = c.Offset(0, 1)
Next i
End sub